# Perl: equivalent of "ubound" in VBA

Tags: arrays, perl

Now that on day 2 of Perl I see that arrays start with element(0) too, how do I get the last index of an array like ubound in VBA rather than the size of it using scalar(@array)?

Is the use of $size = $#array a good way or is there something similar to scalar(@array)?

Comment: [`$#array`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlintro.pod#Arrays). Look over all of [`perlintro`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlintro.pod) before day 2 is over.

Comment: Do you want the last element or the last index?

Comment: Actually index rather than element, sorry.

Comment: You seem to be asking a lot of rather basic questions. That's fine, of course. But I'd be interested to hear what resources you are using to learn Perl as we might be able to point you towards something better.

Comment: Sorry about the basic questions. I have been using perldoc and perlmonks. Trying to get out of Office VBA and rewrite it in Perl. Finding the right "vocab" and syntax to do the same things is sometimes a little confusing.

Comment: @user110084: [This tutorial](https://blog.udemy.com/learn-perl-a-tutorial-to-get-you-started/) that I wrote, might be a good way to get the absolute basics of Perl. But then you should really get a book. I recommend "Learning Perl".

Comment: @user110084: And there's no need at all to apologise for your questions. I wasn't complaining at all - I was just wondering if there was a more efficient way that we could help you.

Comment: Thank you @DaveCross. I am really appreciative of everyone here. I have been putting off moving out of VBA for years, but since I tend to code for specific problems that has not really happened. Reading beginners' guides/tutorials starting with "hello world" and explaining how to do various loops does not help when there is a particular problem to solve. So, I have gone into the deeper end and try to figure out the equivalents on the fly. Hope I am not straining everyone's patience too much here.

Answer (score 6):

Perl's arrays always start empty.

```
my @array;      # equivalent
my @array = (); #
```

To get the highest index, use `$#array`.

```
my @array = qw(a b c);
print $#array; # 2
```

If the array is empty, `$#array` will be `-1`.

Comment: sorry @simbabque, should have chosen my words more carefully, I was looking for the highest index

Comment: @user110084 that's in there too. The last two words of the answer, to be specific. Edited.